# Kafka streams - Trying to filter data from the streams and write to another topic. But returns empty

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

countInput is the KStream here.

```
countInput.print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

I get output as below

```
null, {def=;abc=123;ghi=}
```

I try to get count of "**abc=** " alone.

```
KTable<String, Long> Counts = countInput.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split(";"))).groupBy((key,value) -> value).count();

Counts.filter((key,value) -> key.startsWith("ABC="));
```

But above code doesnt seem to work. Any inputs. Thanks.

Comment: You use `toLowerCase()` -- should it be `toUpperCase()`? Or should it be `key.startsWith("abc=")`?

Answer (score 1):

You are converting all the value to LowerCase in `flatMapValues` operation while filter operation has comparison with UpperCase.

```
Counts.filter((key,value) -> key.startsWith("ABC="));
```

Hence it won't match any key in the stream and return empty. Replace "ABC=" to "abc="

```
Counts.filter((key,value) -> key.startsWith("abc="));
```